# iOS 9 App Crash MKMapView Related?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

The following error pops up in Raygun Periodically, but I have no idea where to begin in the debugging. Just a guess, but could the `MKMapView` I'm using cause this? It seems to happen very rarely. Any ideas?

```
Thread 19 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x1831a8140 0x18318c000 + 115008
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x183119dac abort + 400812
2   libc++abi.dylib               0x182c4d3f4 __cxa_bad_cast + 5108
3   libc++abi.dylib               0x182c69e80 default_terminate_handler( + 122496
4   libobjc.A.dylib               0x182c74264 _objc_terminate( + 33380
5   libc++abi.dylib               0x182c66f44 [std::__terminate(void (*)())] + 110404
6   libc++abi.dylib               0x182c6685c [__cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)] + 108636
7   libc++abi.dylib               0x182c67154 [operator new(unsigned] + 110932
8   VectorKit                     0x18d06928c [std::__1::vector&lt;unsigned char, std::__1::allocator&lt;unsigned char&gt; &gt; __append(unsigned long) ] + 2019980
9   VectorKit                     0x18d275030 [ggl::BufferData::resize(unsigned long)] + 4165680
10  VectorKit                     0x18d215fbc [VKCoastlineGroup addCoastlineFeature:] + 3776444
11  VectorKit                     0x18cfe87bc [std::__1::__function::__func&lt;-[VKPolygonTile buildCoastlinesWithStyleSession:]::$_5, std::__1::allocator&lt;-[VKPolygonTile buildCoastlinesWithStyleSession:] $_5&gt;, void (geo::_retain_ptr&lt;objc_object*, geo::_retain_objc, geo::_release_objc, geo::_hash_objc, geo::_equal_objc&gt;&amp;, std::__1::shared_ptr&lt;gss::StyleQuery&gt;)&gt;::operator()(geo::_retain_ptr&lt;objc_object*, geo::_retain_objc, geo::_release_objc, geo::_hash_objc, geo::_equal_objc&gt;&amp;, std::__1::shared_ptr&lt;gss::StyleQuery&gt;&amp;&amp;) ] + 1492924
12  VectorKit                     0x18cfe8dc4 [gss::StyleResolutionSession&lt;geo::_retain_ptr&lt;objc_object*, geo::_retain_objc, geo::_release_objc, geo::_hash_objc, geo::_equal_objc&gt; &gt; evaluateFeatureCreatingAndAppendingGroup(GEOFeature*, geo::_retain_ptr&lt;objc_object*, geo::_retain_objc, geo::_release_objc, geo::_hash_objc, geo::_equal_objc&gt;, std::__1::function&lt;geo::_retain_ptr&lt;objc_object*, geo::_retain_objc, geo::_release_objc, geo::_hash_objc, geo::_equal_objc&gt; (std::__1::shared_ptr&lt;gss::StyleQuery&gt;, gss::FeatureAttributeSet const&amp;)&gt;, std::__1::function&lt;void (geo::_retain_ptr&lt;objc_object*, geo::_retain_objc, geo::_release_objc, geo::_hash_objc, geo::_equal_objc&gt;&amp;, std::__1::shared_ptr&lt;gss::StyleQuery&gt;)&gt;) ] + 1494468
13  VectorKit                     0x18cfe56d0 [VKPolygonTile buildCoastlinesWithStyleSession:] + 1480400
14  VectorKit                     0x18cfe47f4 [VKPolygonTile initWithKey:modelTile:prepareExtrusion:styleManager:sharedResources:contentScale:device:] + 1476596
15  VectorKit                     0x18ceb1dac [VKPolygonTileSource tileForData:downloadKey:sourceKey:] + 220588
16  VectorKit                     0x18ce9df08 [VKTileSource decodeData:downloadKey:sourceKey:]_block_invoke] + 139016
17  libdispatch.dylib             0x183059630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 5680
18  libdispatch.dylib             0x1830595f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 5616
19  libdispatch.dylib             0x183063ec4 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 48836
20  libdispatch.dylib             0x1830595f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 5616
21  libdispatch.dylib             0x183067a88 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 64136
22  libdispatch.dylib             0x183069aa8 _dispatch_worker_thread + 72360
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x18326fb28 0x18326c000 + 15144
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x18326fa8c 0x18326c000 + 14988
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x18326d028 0x18326c000 + 4136
```

Thanks.